# Deploy customised compiled ejabberd on production

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

How can I easily deploy the customised compiled version of ejabberd into production?

Is there any tool that can generate something like ejabberd-xx-installer.run (similar to https://www.process-one.net/downloads/downloads-action.php?file=/ejabberd/16.06/ejabberd-16.06-linux-x86_64-installer.run)

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker to deploy ejabberd into production. You can use Dockerfile from [this](https://github.com/rroemhild/docker-ejabberd) link and modify it to take your customised code. It will automatically compile code and generate docker which can be deployed in production with just `docker run` command.